# .toUppercase() Function in Google App Script - How to capitalize using Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to capitalize some letters in my code, but everything I've found online hasn't worked. Does anyone know what I can do?

What I have tried is below this code:

```
var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody(); 
var text = doc.editAsText(); 
var letter = alphabet[Math.floor(Math.random()*alphabet.length)];
UPPER(letter); also letter.toUppercase() return letter;
```

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried?

Comment: var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var text = doc.editAsText();
  
  
  var letter = alphabet[Math.floor(Math.random()*alphabet.length)];
  UPPER(letter); also letter.toUppercase()
   
  return letter;

Comment: You need to return the result of calling string methods, not the object those methods were invoked on

Comment: So should I store the letter.toUppercase in a variable then return that?

Comment: Where is alphabet defined? Provide [mcve]. You should use `text.replaceText(letter, letter.toUpperCase())` instead.

Comment: Thanks so much! I set alphabet as universal array at the very top and forgot to copy it. Thanks so much!